# Help create a great Wikipedia entry for Ask Ubuntu

Tags: discussion, promote

Please help by making http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AskUbuntu , the Wikipedia entry about AskUbuntu better. You may want to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StackOverflow as a reference on how our page should probably look like.

Comment: I've improved the wiki article a bit and made a quick case on the talk page as to why it shouldn't be speedily deleted.

Comment: @fluteflute Great

Answer (score 4):

I promised to update the Wikipedia page in my nomination post. Even though I didn't get elected, I think it is only fair to keep the Wikipedia page updated. Hence, I have decided to maintain the page for the foreseeable future.

So, I am looking for opinions for what should be described in the article and what should be kept out. Please post your opinions as comments or other answers.

Comment: Nice! I guess an Etherpad or a Google Docs text document wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean That sound like a good idea the first few times, but why when you could just write it on Wikipedia as it mostly has the same sort of function as a Google Doc. Please don't cite some obscure highlighter function.