# Should we create task items for better managing the site?

Tags: discussion, community

So, as each day goes by, we are growing bigger and bigger, both in terms of the size as well as the participating members. Now, that is not essentially a bad thing to happen. But it does present some interesting problems.

As we grow bigger, we tend to neglect parts of the site that aren't so much visible for the commoners of the site but does deserve attention for what they are.

Now, I have put together a small list of things both on and off the site that could use some attention. I would like it if interested parties take care of one or more of these task items and work on them on a regular basis.

Anyways, here's the list:

1. Review the suggested edits reviews.

   - Check if edits are mistakenly approved or rejected
2. Cleanup new tags (requires 500 rep).

   - Remove new and bad tags before they grow out of control
3. Tag wikis

   - Make them more awesome - http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3977/what-makes-a-tag-wiki-good
   - Also handle plagiarism - http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3582/what-to-do-with-plagiarized-tag-wikis
   - Possibly include FAQ in that tag inside of tag wiki for better canonical questions management
4. Take care of meta

   - Editing for general readability
   - Retag them with appropriate tags.
   - Make sure the posts are readable.
5. Post updates on Planet Ubuntu (I am doing this at the moment)

   - Updates about hot questions and top users of the month.
   - Also, important decisions made in the month in meta.
6. [Monthly update of Wikipedia article](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/573/help-create-a-great-wikipedia-entry-for-ask-ubuntu) (I am supposed to do this but I have neglected it over time)

   - Update stats and other minor niggles.
7. [Regularly update Google+ feeds.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2106/what-should-be-posted-on-ask-ubuntus-google-page) (The mods, Jorge Castro and myself)

   - Post Planet Ubuntu updates.
   - Awesome questions and answers.
   - Important decisions and discussions in meta.
8. Tumbleweeds

   - Improve them, retag them, vote on them, add more info, etc
9. [Greatest hits of the site](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2671/how-can-we-improve-the-greatest-hits-of-our-site).

   - Retag them, specific title, screenshots, improved instructions.
10. Follow 2500 views questions and improve them.

    - Same as Greatest hits
11. [IRC bots for channels](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3179/how-about-adding-rss-feeds-for-certain-tags-in-irc-channels). Be a bot contact, improve them, add to new channels, engage the channels, etc. (Amith was working on it last time)

    - Make a bot and build an interface to deploy bots. Sit on the chat room and see if it is buggy.
    - Build a closer community with IRC and Ask Ubuntu
12. [Take care of version tags](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4124/psa-when-reviewing-remember-to-think-of-the-future). (Might need significant number of users)

    - Remove tags where unnecessary - http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4124/psa-when-reviewing-remember-to-think-of-the-future
13. Bounty questions.

    - Every bounty question needs to be spruced up. Go through the bounty tab everyday and improve the question where necessary. Edit in the details from the comments. Improve answers, add screenshots, fix formatting, etc
14. Fix Misspelled Ubuntus.

    - Fix all the wrong Ubuntu! (P.S. Last time I checked, there was quite a bit. Would require effort initially to clear up the backlog)
    - [0](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Ubunto+Ubunut+Ubunutu+Ubunu+Ubntu+Ubutnu+Uuntu+Unbuntu+Ubunty+Ubunt+Ubintu+Ubutu&submit=search) [1](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Ubantu+Ubbuntu+Ubnuntu+Ubnuto+Ubnutu+Ububntu+Ububtu+Ubuhntu+Ubuhtu+Ubunbtu+Ubunti+Ubuntuu&submit=search) [2](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Ubunuto+Ubutno+Ubuto+Ubuuntu+Ubuutu+Unbnuto+Unbnutu+Unbunto+Unbunu+Ununtu+Uubuntu+Ybuntu&submit=search) [3](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Ubguntu+Ubhntu+Ubhuntu+Ubiuntu+Ubjntu+Ubjuntu+Ubkntu+Ubkuntu+Ubuintu+Ubujntu+Ubujtu+Ubukntu&submit=search) [4](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Ubumntu+Ubumtu+Ubunftu+Ubunfu+Ubungtu+Ubungu+Ubunhtu+Ubunhu+Ubunjtu+Ubunmtu+Ubunntu+Ubunot&submit=search) [5](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Ubunoto+Ubunrtu+Ubunru+Ubuntfu+Ubuntgu+Ubunth+Ubunthu+Ubuntiu+Ubuntj+Ubuntju+Ubuntk+Ubuntku&submit=search) [6](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Ubuntru+Ubunttu+Ubuntuh+Ubuntui+Ubuntuj+Ubuntuk+Ubuntuy+Ubuntyu+Ubunytu+Ubunyu+Ubuyntu+Ubvuntu&submit=search) [7](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Ubyntu+Ubyuntu+Ugbuntu+Uguntu+Uhbuntu+Uhuntu+Unbunot+Unbunoto+Uvbuntu+Uvuntu&submit=search")
15. Flag queue (Requires 10K+)

    - Add proforma comments to flags where necessary. Validate and invalidate flags as usual.
16. Delete queue. (Requires 10K+)

    - Keep hold of the delete queue. If needed, can create a new chat room for posting questions with outstanding delete votes.
17. Hot questions per day / week / month

    - Hot questions tab should be updated and made more awesome.
    - Three groups for each of the tab would be great.
18. [Tweeted questions](http://twitter.com/askubuntu)

    - Closely follow the questions posted on Twitter and make sure that they are in tip top fashion. They sorta show what Ask Ubuntu is about to the general public
    - Might need members around the clock to maintain quality throughout the day.
19. Interact with the larger Ubuntu community for community events (I am guessing Jorge Castro already deals with this.)

    - Prepare a chat transcript for Open week. We can possibly reuse it every time with minor alterations.
    - Ubuntu accomplishment systems (write documentation, etc)
20. Keep the tags that are posted in the IRC chat clean.

    - Improve them, edit them etc. They showcase what sort of a community Ask Ubuntu is.. ;)
21. [Fix broken links posts](https://askubuntu.com/review/broken-links)
22. [Keep track of posts on the newsletters](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=askubuntu.com).

    - Improve them, edit them, fix grammar, add screenshots, edit title, etc

#### General things everyone can chip in:

1. Answer new questions :D
2. Vote on new posts. The more reputation we generate, the more community custodians we get. The more the merrier.
3. Edit posts for grammar and formatting as you see on the site.
4. Close posts from the review queue.
5. Review Low quality, first posts and late answers.
6. Contribute more task items. :D

---

Some tasks might require more than just a single person. I haven't specified how many personnel each of the tasks would need because I can't exactly predict the kind of reaction for this post. So I didn't want to spend too much energy into this if no one is remotely interested.

One community member has already made it clear that he is not interested in doing free voluntary unpaid delegate work. (If you already didn't know, you probably won't get anything of actual value in real life for what you are doing but I'll be glad to email you a thank you message if you want one. :-))

And I haven't asked any of the community moderators for their opinions but I hope they don't mind this because I hope this will help make Ask Ubuntu an even better place and also possibly, create a community spirit in the site which I think is largely wanting.

If the general consensus towards this idea is positive from the community, I can create a Trello board if necessary and you can assign the card to yourself and take care of the task items as you wish.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

<sub>OK. Fine. I'll admit the truth. I go through some of the things once in a while when I feel bored. But I am getting increasingly inefficient as time goes by and I would like some additional help. If a good number of people are at least marginally interested, that would be great and much appreciated.</sub>

Comment: The *ubuntu* typo link is now outdated.

Comment: It isn't outdated. The new search feature works differently now. More search terms will reduce the scope. So, try searching for each of the misspelled Ubuntus instead.

Answer (score 7):

We have a Trello board, feel free to use it!:

- [Ask Ubuntu - Trello](https://trello.com/board/ask-ubuntu/4ec557e6ea86c7153d127fc5)

Though I don't think we need to put general "maintenance-y" type things on there like correcting mispellings and whatnot, at some point it becomes burdensome to do meta-work when we could be doing real work.

So I say just put the things that we need to be reminded of doing, like Wikipedia, the blogging, and so on on the Trello board, and then the other stuff just plop it in the editing guy: [Editing tips and tricks](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/830/editing-tips-and-tricks)

Sincerely,

A guy who spent way too much time writing up guides and meta-work on Meta that subsequently is never read by anyone so I just concentrate on doing real work instead of collating lists.